# What is the probability of subsequences

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose a coin is biased for a heads outcome upon tossing by 95%.  Suppose the coin is tossed $10,000$ times and for each toss, indexed by $i$, $x_i$ was set equal to $1$ if the outcome of the toss was heads and otherwise $x_i$ was set to $0$.

What is the probability that there is at least one sequence of $100$ consecutive $x_i$'s such that:

$$\frac{1}{100}\sum_{i}x_i<0.95\;\text{?}$$

And, more generally, what is the probability as a function of $k$, an integer between $1$ and $100$ inclusive, that there will be at least $k$ disjoint sequences of $100$ consecutive $x_i$'s such that:

$$\frac{1}{100}\sum_{i}x_i<0.95$$

for each such sequence of $x_i$'s?

After thinking about this for a couple of days, I believe the first question may be answered as follows:

$$P\left(\sum_{i \le 100}x_{i}<95\right)+P\left(\sum_{i>100}x_{i}<9405\right)=P\left(\sum_{i>100}x_{i}<9500\right)$$

where, without loss of generality, it's assumed that the one sequence of $100$ consecutive $x_i$'s occurs for $1{\le}i{\le}100$ and $P{\left(E\right)}$ is the probability of $E$.

$$P\left(\sum_{i \le 100}x_{i}<95\right)=1-P\left(\sum_{i>100}x_{i}<9405\right)$$

$$P\left(\sum_{i \le 100}x_{i}<95\right)=1-\frac{9405}{9900}=1-0.95$$

$$P\left(\sum_{i \le 100}x_{i}<95\right)=0.05$$

Therefore, there is a 5% probability or chance that there is at least one sequence of $100$ consecutive $x_i$'s such that $\frac{1}{100}\sum_{i}x_i<0.95$.  This result actually makes sense.  And I am writing that term in that manner because it has more to do with the specific application I'm working with (answer to the "sophisticated" question in the comment section).

Comment: What's the point in writing that $\frac{1}{100}$? Are you trying to make your question look more sophisticated? Just write $95$ on the other side.

Comment: BTW, for the first question, a single *Tail* anywhere in that sequence of $10000$ tosses is enough to guarantee a sequence of $100$ consecutive tosses that sums up to less than $95$. So you can simply calculate "one minus the probability of the complementary event": $1-0.95^{10000}$.

Comment: Can that be correct?  Suppose for the same coin and for the same number of tossing, the goal was to calculate the probability that there is at least one sequence of $100$ consecutive $x_i$'s such that $\sum_{i}x_{i} \le 1.0$. The method you outlined above would tell me that the probability of such an occurrence would be: $1-0.01^{10000} = 1-\left(1.0E-20000\right)$. For all practical purposes, this value is $1$. Common sense would tell me that the probability of such an occurrence would be nearly $0$ not $1$. Please explain as I would like to very much understand this problem.